# Accessing windows applications controls from class library c# windows application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class-library

i wanted to disable form control from class library, means i added one class named as **clsInit** method & i called this method when i'm loading the form in main project,so i need find the control which one i wanted to disable.

 Is it possible to find loaded form controls in class library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Form.Controls` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) is what you need.

You can pass the reference of your form into your library, and access its controls via `Controls` property.

Answer (score 0):

You may create an object of your form, as:

```
MyForm frm = new MyForm();
```

...then select the controls to be disabled:

```
foreach (Control control in frm.Controls)
{
    if(control.Name == "cboSomeDdn")
        control.Enabled = false;
}
```

and then load the form (this one :

```
frm.Load()
```

or

```
frm.Show()
```

If this is a one form application, you may also set this as a starting point:

```
Application.Run(frm);
```

> Please use this answer as a starting point and not as a copy-paste
>   solution. Also ensure to follow best-practices of development in the
>   language of your choice.

Hope this helps!

Vivek